# Protect WordPress option value

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options

I'm working on a plugin and users need to create and store some unencrypted credentials in wp-options. The credentials in question are service keys for google server to server API which is just a json or p12 file, therefore these creds are both unencrypted and [cannot be restricted for use from other servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381591/restricting-google-api-server-to-server-service-account-key-to-be-used-with-spec) (which is weird). Storing these creds either as a file or in wp-options would pose a pretty obvious exploit. Is there something that could be done on the WP side in order to prevent access to a particular option or file for 3rd party plugins?

Comment: You could encrypt/decrypt them using a static key in your plugin. The question really is against which attackers you're trying to protect it from

Comment: Even if there were a way to restrict access to the option or file via WP, it would still be vulnerable to anyone who gained database or ftp access. There isn't a safe way to store anything unencrypted.

Comment: @kero I want to protect the option from being accessed by a 3rd party plugin using simple `get_option ()`. The static key wouldn't do much because it would have to be stored in the options as well or read if its stored in plugin file.

Comment: @WebElaine totally agree, however you will probably agree that using `get_option()` to retrieve the credentials would be several orders of magnitude easier than hacking into someones hosting.

Comment: And what is the problem with storing the key in your plugin file? Yes, other plugins would be able to read them (if they read the file, etc.) - but you will probably not get around this at all

Comment: @kero The problem is that whoever has the file, can establish a server to server connection and access user data, which is unacceptable. As I said in the question, the key use cannot be restricted for use from specific IPs or domains, which is a huge inconvenience.

Comment: This will always be the problem. And it's the site owners task to only use the needed plugins as well as trust

Comment: Either get your users to get their own keys, or use an API on your server to proxy all requests, use a unique client key to authenticate them and don't give your credentials out at all.

Comment: @janh users will need to generate their keys, that's the idea. Proxying a request will give me nothing since a rogue plugin can get API creds from wp_options and query my server. This is really frustrating.

Comment: A plugin has basically all the powers of the user itself, on his server. All you can do is damage control, in which your API comes in and might throttle / disable this particular user / server. You could make it harder, of course, and use ZendGuard etc to hide your protocol, but it'll also limit the ability of your users to run your plugin.

Comment: What @janh says. Plugins are not sandboxed or something and can access everything on the server or in the database. Since your users will need to generate their own keys anyway, I don't see why it's even necessary to try to protect these keys. It's not your fault if they get compromised. Any effort to try to protect these keys will not be worth it and will most likely hurt the user experience.

Comment: @janh Perhaps you are right. I have similar thread [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/protecting-a-value-in-wp_options/?view=all#post-9889942) And the gurus there came to the same conclusion. This is kinda bad. I'd upwote everyone's comments but I have too little rep. Thank you!